# What is the definition of a $\kappa$-closed ideal in set theory?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

Exercise 16.19 of Jech's *Set Theory* says:

> Let $I$ be a $\kappa$-closed ideal on $\alpha$, and let $P_\alpha$ be an iteration of $\{\dot{Q}_\beta\}_\beta$ with $I$-support. If for each $\beta < \alpha$, $\Vdash_\beta \dot{Q}_\beta$ is $<\!\kappa$-closed, then $P_\alpha$ is $<\!\kappa$-closed.

However, Jech did not define what a $\kappa$-closed ideal is. I also can't seem to find any literature defining what it means for an ideal to be $\kappa$-closed. I would appreciate if someone can help me on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal of set $I$ is $\kappa$-closed if whenever $\gamma<\kappa$ and $\{A_\alpha\mid\alpha<\gamma\}\subseteq I$, then $\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma}A_\alpha\in I$. In other words, the ideal is closed under $<\kappa$-sized unions.

Every ideal is $\omega$-closed, but not every ideal is $\omega_1$-closed, or $\sigma$-closed as it is often called in that case.

Comment: I see, so it is equivalent to $\kappa$-completeness?

Comment: Yes. If I had to guess, I'd say it's a misprint. I think you're overthinking this.